# Android: Why do I have to use runOnUIThread() Here?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I am working on a simple game with graphics using Open GL. I want it so that when a certain event happens, the player gets a point, and this updates a textview overlaying the GLSurfaceView on the game activity.

Thanks in advance!

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

The Activity:

```
public class playActivity extends Activity {

private GLSurfaceView myGLView;
private Handler mGameHandler;
private TextView mScoreView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mScoreView = new TextView(this);
    mScoreView.setTextColor(0xFF00FF00); // Green
    string myZeroString = "0";
    mScoreView.setText(myZeroString); //Starting score will always be 0

    mGameHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            if (msg.what == MyGLRenderer.GAME_SCORE_FLAG) {
                int score = msg.arg1;
                mScoreView.setText(Integer.toString(score));
            }

        }
    };

    myGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(myGLView);

    addContentView(mScoreView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

}

private void updateScoreBoard(int score){
    mScoreView.setText(Integer.toString(score));
}


class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView{

    private final MyGLRenderer myRenderer;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);

        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        myRenderer = new MyGLRenderer(context);
        myRenderer.initiateHandler(mGameHandler);

        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        setRenderer(myRenderer);

        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }


    }

}
```

And the GlSurfaceView.Renderer:

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

    public static final int GAME_SCORE_FLAG = 1;
    private Handler mGameHandler = null;
    private int mScore = 0;

    public void initiateHandler(Handler handler){
        mGameHandler = handler;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused){

        if (scoreCondition){
            mScore += 1;
            if (mGameHandler != null) {
                int flag = MyGLRenderer.GAME_SCORE_FLAG;
                mGameHandler.dispatchMessage(Message.obtain(mGameHandler, flag, 2));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

When I run this, it gives me the error: 
"android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

However, in the top chunk of code, when I replace

```
int score = msg.arg1;
mScoreView.setText(Integer.toString(score));
```

with

```
 final int score = 3;
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         mScoreView.setText(Integer.toString(score));
     }
 });
```

I no longer get the error and it works. I thought that in the first construction that when I called setText that it would have to be performed on the UI thread, but Android Studio thinks differently. Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
mGameHandler.dispatchMessage(Message.obtain(mGameHandler, flag, 2));
```

to:

```
mGameHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(mGameHandler, flag, 2));
```

Calling `dispatchMessage()` will cause the message to be delivered on the current thread (which is the GL thread in your case.)